# Does somebody know where to find subtitles for Kureyon Shin-chan?

Tags: crayon-shin-chan

I've gotten this set of Kureyon Shin-Chan episodes from a friend (クレヨンしんちゃん (Crayon Shin Chan) DVD TV版傑作選) but they don't have subtitles. Does somebody know where could I find english subs for these?

Comment: Is this for a DVD?

Comment: I just have the video files, I'm not sure if he had the DVDs or not.

Comment: sadly I doubt Shin Chan is a kids cartoon, because it is all adult content. Even with that said I know of only one episode that you can find that has sub titles, and that is episode 1. sorry.

Comment: Subtitled versions DO exist, but jeez! They are rare!! There was a place in NYC's Chinatown in the 90s that had a half dozen video tapes (all on EP speed) crammed full of episodes with subs. They came from Hawaiian television. Someone, somewhere, has to have better quality copies of those... but I can't find them!! The VHS tapes I used to have are no longer playable (damned EP tapes!), and all I have now is about 5 subbed episodes that I found on the internet ten years ago. It's a shame these aren't subbed officially and released on DVD or blu-ray. The show is absolutely hilarious and fun!

Comment: They were broadcast by [KIKU-TV](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/company.php?id=4973) in Hawaii. Which was a subbed release.

Comment: I agree the show is so funny, the only way I watched it,(which seems crazy now) was because my ex would translate. Thanks for the info guys, maybe with this it'll be easier to hunt them down. I've just found some on youtube, here's the link just incase anyone is interested.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMAm17edjY8

Comment: This whole question should probably be closed as "requesting illegal or copyrighted materials" as it sounds like the OP has a bunch of raw video files, which doesn't sound terribly legal, and is looking for subtitle files to load onto them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there are any subtitled releases of *Crayon Shin-chan*. [The show's ANN page](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=540) lists multiple Region 1 releases, but all of them are dubbed (and don't even include the Japanese audio, except for bonus episodes).

In general, don't count on being able to find subtitled versions of children's shows - if children's shows do get released in an English-speaking country, they'll almost certainly be dubbed. After all, their target audience is children, and children aren't very good at reading subtitles.

Comment: Fair enough I guess I'll just take it as a reason to keep on trying to learn Japanese. Gotta say though, how Shin-Chan can be aimed at a younger audience is beyond me. It's so perverted!

Comment: @mac_fan_33 - welcome to cultural differences!

Comment: @senshin [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crayon_Shin-chan) notes the demographic as seinen.

Comment: @mac_33 Shin-chan isn't a kid's show. After it gained popularity they sort of made it SLIGHTLY more kid friendly but it's well known to be aimed at young adults. The manga appeared in Weekly Manga Action which is aimed at adults.